# Getting a max value from an array, where there could be multiple max values

Tags: arrays, vb.net, max, display

I have made an array of ages from a database and wish the find the maximum values in the array. I have made this code so far...

```
    Dim MaxAge, MaxIndex, MaxCount As Integer

    MaxAge = arrAge(1)
    MaxIndex = 1

    For MaxCount = 2 To Length
        If MaxAge < arrAge(MaxCount) Then
            MaxAge = arrAge(MaxCount)
            MaxIndex = MaxCount
        End If
    Next

    lstDisplayMax.Items.Add(arrAge(MaxIndex))
```

This code works, however, If there are two or more maxes in the array, it will still only result in one of the maximum values being displayed. I need it to display all the max values. Thank in advance :)

Comment: Does that really make sense though? Let's say that you have an array of 20 values and the largest value is 50 and that appears three times in the array.  What you've asked for will give you 50 three times.  Is that really what you want?  If so then it can be done quite easily with a couple of lines of code but does it really provide the information you need?

Comment: Also, does the code you have even work? An array starts at index 0 and goes to index (Length - 1) so your code looks like it will miss the first element and throw an `IndexOutOfRangeExeption`.

Comment: Yeah that's what i want, I know it sounds odd and pointless. It's kinda hard to explain but basically, I've gotten this 'Age' array from multiple 'Patient Profiles' in a database and i want to find the max values. I will then put these max values back into the database along with the rest of the data from that profile.

Comment: Yeah it works. in the database i have two 'patients' with an age 43. The list box displays 43, so it does work but it only displays one of the ages. Sorry btw if I'm bad at explaining things and my methods are basic, I'm a bit new to all this. :)

Comment: You might try providing the full story in future. You said that you wanted the ages when what you actually wanted was the entire records that went along with those ages. If you had provided that information from the outset then the solution would have been fairly clear.  By the way, if you want the max value from an array then you simply do this: `Dim max = myArray.Max()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. All you have to do is create a filter for the database using the `arrAge(maxindex)`. It will display all the records in the database that share the max age.

The code goes like this:

```
Dim MaxAge, MaxIndex, MaxCount As Integer
Dim Length As Integer = Me.listName.Items.Count - 1

MaxAge = arrAge(1)
MaxIndex = 1

For MaxCount = 2 To Length
    If MaxAge < arrAge(MaxCount) Then
       MaxAge = arrAge(MaxCount)
       MaxIndex = MaxCount
    End If
Next

Me.PatientListingBindingSource.Filter = "pAge = '" & arrAge(MaxIndex) & "' "
```

Comment: That filter doesn't quite make sense.  Presumably your `pAge` column contains numbers.  You don't wrap numbers in single quotes in SQL code.  That's just for text, just as wrapping in double quotes in just for text in VB.